# persistir el inicio de sesión en Android

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación android. Realicé mi inicio de sesión, todo correcto. Pero tengo un problema al momento en que doy en el boton de retroceder de mi celular cuando me encuentro en mi actividad principal, es decir el que está al costado del home, ya que es como si cerrara sesión.

Como podría hacer que persista la sesión y no se cierre?

Actualmente solo tengo el inicio y el cierre de sesión con el siguiente código.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private final String clientId = "your-client-id";
    //private final String clientSecret = "password";
    //private final String redirectUri = "your://redirecturi";

    private final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
    private final String AUTHORIZATION = "Basic d2ViOnNlY3JldA==";

    TextInputEditText edt_user_account;
    TextInputEditText edt_password;
    CheckBox chk_rememberme;
    Button btn_login;
    private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

    AccessToken access_token;
    String user = null;
    String password = null;

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        chk_rememberme = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_rememberme);
        edt_user_account = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_user_account);
        edt_password = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesG11", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        user = prefs.getString("user_account", "");
        password = prefs.getString("password", "");
        //String user = "jvelasquez@applying.pe";
        //String password = "123456789";
        if(user!=null&&!user.isEmpty()&&password!=null&&!password.isEmpty()){
            login();
        }else {
            btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    user = edt_user_account.getText().toString();
                    password = edt_password.getText().toString();
                    if (password != null && !password.isEmpty() && user != null && !user.isEmpty()) {
                        login();
                    } else if (user == null || user.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.user_is_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if (password == null || password.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.password_is_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void login() {
        LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
        Call<AccessToken> call = loginService.getAccessToken("password", password, user, CONTENT_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
//                     if (response.isSuccess()) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    access_token = response.body();
                    System.out.println("LOGIN ACCESS TOKEN ->"+access_token.getAccess_token());

                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.remove("user_account");
                    editor.remove("password");
                    editor.remove("access_token");
                    editor.remove("user_bean");
                    editor.commit();

                    if(chk_rememberme.isChecked()) {
                        editor.putString("user_account", user);
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                    }

                    editor.putString("access_token", access_token.getAccess_token());

                    /*DATOS DEL USUARIO*/
                    LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
                    Call<UserAccountBean> callMe = loginService.getUserLogged(access_token.getAccess_token());

                    callMe.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccountBean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Response<UserAccountBean> response) {
                            UserAccountBean userAccountBean = response.body();
                            editor.putString("user_fisrt_name",userAccountBean.getFirstName());
                            editor.putString("user_pattern_name",userAccountBean.getPatternName());
                            editor.putString("user_mail",userAccountBean.getUsername());
                            editor.putLong("user_id",userAccountBean.getId());

                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {
                // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.login_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Aprecio su ayuda,

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes ser más específico? Desde que actividad te pasa eso, desde la principal? Qué has probado? Mira este enlace y edita tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: exactamente. desde la actividad principal, la cual aparece despues del inicio de sesión.